# Return user information after validate user in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure to validate a user. After validate right now I am returning true if user is validated but how can I return all the details of that user instead of true?

```
IF (@Flag='Authenticate')
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT UserID  FROM UserInformation WITH(NOLOCK)WHERE UserName=@UserName and Password=@UserPassword )
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO UserLoginHistory(UserId,LastLoggedIn)
  SELECT @Userid,GETDATE()
  select 'true' as [Output] 
 END
END
```

Comment: I hope you aren't storing plain passwords in your database.I'm also not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "How do I return all the info"? What is "all the info"?

Comment: @SchmitzIT I meant all the column value

Comment: You can either select as many columns as you like, i.e. return a dataset, or use output parameters. There are loads of examples of both around.

Comment: Related - stop splattering [nolock hints everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). That is NOT a best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below query -  You can declare more variables as needed, and store all those information in variables which you want to return.

```
IF (@Flag='Authenticate')
BEGIN

Declare @UserID varchar(50) = null

SELECT @UserID = UserID  FROM UserInformation WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE UserName=@UserName and Password=@UserPassword )
 IF (@UserID is not NULL)
 BEGIN

  INSERT INTO UserLoginHistory(UserId,LastLoggedIn)
  SELECT @Userid,GETDATE()

  SELECT @Userid 
 END
END
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Comment: @C.Das - if the user not found or password incorrect, the procedure will not return anything and you need to handle it on server-side code/ front end. Let me know you will face any challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate "if" to check if the user already exists.  You can put that all into a single query:

```
IF (@Flag = 'Authenticate')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserLoginHistory(UserId, LastLoggedIn)
        SELECT v.Userid, GETDATE()
        FROM (VALUES (@UserId)) v(UserId)
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM UserInformation ui
                      WHERE ui.UserName = @UserName AND ui.Password = @UserPassword
                     );

     SELECT ui.*
     FROM UserInformation ui
     WHERE ui.UserName = @UserName AND ui.Password = @UserPassword;
END;
```

Also, I am concerned about `@UserPassword`.  Hopefully that value is encrypted!  You should not have clear-text passwords anywhere in an application that has a user other than you -- even for a demo or course.